# How can get number and power of it that written in scientific form separately in R?

Tags: r

I want to get number and its power separately in scientific form. For example if my  number be `1.23e-100` I want to get `1.23` and `-100` separately in R.

One of way that I think It's possible to get it separately by converting the number into string and separate it based on before of `e` and after of it. but I want a function for it.

Is there any function for this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those pieces using `log`

```
x = 1.23e-100
floor(log(x, 10))
[1] -100
10^(log(x,10) - floor(log(x, 10)))
[1] 1.23
```

As I wrote this,  it will only work for numbers bigger than zero.

Comment: [Related information](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Built-in-function-for-extracting-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-numeric-td4670116.html)